# how to retrieve the keys and values from a nested jsonobject using gson in java?

Tags: json, gson

Which is the best solution to retrieve all the keys and values from a complex nested jsonObject using gson library in java?

I thought of implementing it in  the following way. But iteration was keep on increasing for complex nested jsonobject 
If element is JSON Object then iterate it into field names and JSON elements and process those JSON elements. 
If element is JSON Array then iterate it into JSON elements and process those JSON elements.
If element is JSON Primitive then print its value as String
For eg. Please find my sample json

`{"address":{"name":"Deepa","street":"qwe","pincode":"234567","state":"Mumbai","country":"India"},"Foo":{"bar":{"id":"string","aa":"bb","aaa":"bbb","ccc":{"ddd":"eee","fff":"ggg","hh":"iii","duration":{"fromDate":"2015-04-13T00:00:00","toDate":"2015-05-27T00:00:00"},"firstCollectionDate":"2015-04-14T00:00:00"},"qqq":"zzz","ss":{"dd":"ff","tt":"wertyt"},"eerr":{"fffkjku":123,"cavcfgv":"ryty"},"sfgfg":{"memo":"hi","status":"open"}},"ffa":{}}}`

Comment: What if you just parse the JSON to `JsonElement` and just process the latter recursively?

Comment: Parsing the json to jsonelement?Sorry ..I didnt get it.

Comment: Let me give a try..

Comment: Is there any generic way how to iterate through jsonObject?

Answer (score 0):

Use can do this recursively as follows :

```
public static Object getValue(JSONObject jsonObject, String key)
{
    if(jsonObject.has(key))
    {
        return jsonObject.get(key);
    }

    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Object value = jsonObject.get(iterator.next());
        if(value instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            return getValue((JSONObject) value, key);
        }
        else if(value instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < ((JSONArray) value).length(); i++)
            {
                return getValue(((JSONArray) value).getJSONObject(i), key);
            }
        }
    }
    return "not found";
}
```